# How to use arithmetic operator in property of spring xml context files

Tags: spring, spring-el

I have this piece of code I am trying to get it work . Total stadium is a property of int type in class Team, it has getters and setters method.

I want to use an arithmetic operator but gives error in the syntax of value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="nameId" class="com.valentine.Namer">

        <property name="name">
            <value>java-beat</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--teams-->
    <bean id="nigeriaId" class="com.valentine.Team">
        <property name="name">
            <value>nigeria</value>
        </property>

        <property name="players">
            <set>
                <ref bean="mikel"/>
                <ref bean="john"/>
                <ref bean="kaita"/>
            </set>
        </property>

        <property name="totalStadium" value="$(2 * 3)"/> // iget an error here cannot compile or accept syntax

    </bean>
```

What am I doing wrong ? thank you in advance.
This is the error I am getting

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'totalStadium'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$(2*3)"
```

Comment: How is this related to Java? All I see is some XML. We have no idea of what that XML is, what it's supposed to represent, in which context it's being used, what error is being thrown, and by what, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet I just added a better explanation

Comment: Hi Valik, I think the syntax for EL is `${...}` or `#{..}` is this what you are trying

Comment: So it's actually a question about Spring XML context files and the Spring expression language. Not about java or java beans. Use the correct tags for your question.

Comment: @JBNizet yes thank you

Comment: @Nishant  hi  can u please vote the question to help me remove a ban ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring 3.0 comes with Spring EL  you can use this

```
  <property name="totalStadium" value="${2 * 3}"/>
```

Comment: @valik Okay shall you review my answers and questions in my profile if you benefit from them vote

Comment: yes I will , hey u are also a junior developer , me too still looking for my first job

Comment: @valik Actually i am working now in Fawry integrated services

Comment: great that is hoping to get next year